# Getting an error while passing the data using Axios client down to the child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm trying to pass the data to the child component and render it, but getting an error.

```js
import axios from 'axios';
import React from 'react';
import MovieCard from './MovieCard';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const Movies = () => {
  let [data, setData] = useState({ data: [] });

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const result = await axios('https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/films');

      setData(result.data);
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  console.log(data);

  //   return <MovieCard data={data} />;
  return (
    <div>
      {data.data.map((item) => {
        return <MovieCard key={item.id} data={data} />;
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Movies;
```

And here is the child component

```js
import React from 'react';

const MovieCard = (props) => {
  const { id, title, description, people } = props;
  console.log(props);
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{title}</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

export default MovieCard;
```

I tried to map through data.map() or data.data.map() but I'm getting errors anyways.

How could I pass the data?

Answer (score 0):

you should write like this:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import React from 'react';
import MovieCard from './MovieCard';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const Movies = () => {
  let [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const result = await axios('https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/films');
 
      if(result && result.data){
      setData(result.data);
      }
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  console.log(data)
  //   return <MovieCard data={data} />;
  return (
    <div>
      {data.map((item) => {
        return <MovieCard key={item.id} title={item.title} />;
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Movies;
```